# Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints when connecting to JDBC MS SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I'm trying to connect my `Spring` application to a `Microsoft SQL Server` database but I am getting the following error:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause
 java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints
```

I have already tried to remove the *JDK's certpath* setting to be blank like: `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=`

Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.abc.cet.eai.repository.sql")
@PropertySource("classpath:eai.application.properties")
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        SQLServerDataSource dataSource = new SQLServerDataSource();
        dataSource.setServerName("SERVERNAME");
        dataSource.setUser("USERNAME");
        dataSource.setPassword("PASSWORD");
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("DATABASE_NAME");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.abc.cet.eai.domain");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return txManager;
    }

    public Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Has anyone solved a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically experiencing the same issue as I did in [WAGON-470](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WAGON-470). The certifacate with created with MD5 which is rejected by modern Java. You should inspect the certificate itself, the ciphers the server is offering and enable JSSE debug opts. IT is likely that you need to update/exchange your certificate wich a more secure method like SHA256.